# How to get all data on my x axis in Python from csv File

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

CSV FILE:

```
Words,Count
ca,110
tc,103
cg,103
gt,100
cc,98
at,96
gc,95
ct,95
aa,94
ta,94
ac,94
tt,91
ag,87
gg,84
ga,79
tg,77
```

Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.plot(kind='line', x='Words', y='Count',logx=True,logy=True)
plt.show()
```

When I've got my plot i see this:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFzCg.png)

How can I get all this letters on my X axis from CSV file because i only have for example ac and tc ?

Update

I've got now another problem when i use CSV File which look like this:

```
Words,Count
tgc,25
tca,24
agt,22
gac,22
gtc,22
cag,21
caa,21
ctg,21
act,21
atg,20
aaa,20
aat,20
cgt,20
att,20
gta,20
ttc,19
cct,19
ctt,18
agc,18
gct,18
cgg,18
ata,18
aag,18
tac,18
aca,18
cac,18
gtt,17
ggg,17
cgc,17
cta,17
gcc,17
cca,17
tcc,16
acc,16
tcg,16
atc,16
aga,15
gat,15
gtg,15
ttt,15
tat,15
gaa,14
tct,14
ccg,14
ggt,14
acg,13
gga,13
ccc,13
aac,12
gca,12
tgg,12
tta,12
cga,12
ctc,11
gag,11
gcg,11
agg,11
cat,11
ttg,11
ggc,9
tgt,9
tga,1
```

My plot looks like this : [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tePMz.png)
Is there any chance to see everything clearly on my x axis ?
My code now :

```
df = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

ax=df.plot(kind='line', y='Count',logx=False,logy=True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df.index)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['Words'])
plt.figure(figsize=(10,30))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the index for the ticks and the Series for the labels.

```
...
ax = df.plot(kind='line', y='Count')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df.index)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['Words'])
plt.show()
```

Or just:

```py
df.plot(x='Words',y='Count',xticks=df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you have set the x-axis to be logarithmic as well. Was this intentionally? My guess it that it was not - at least I would not know how to interpret a log-scale axis with text labels only.

Try it with a logarithmic y-axis only and set x-ticks and x-labels explicitly:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
ax = df.plot(kind='line', x='Words', y='Count',logx=False,logy=True)

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df.index)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['Words'])

plt.show()
```

(`logx=False` can also be omitted as it is the default.)

[image]

Comment: Will that show **all** the labels in the first column of the csv?

Comment: It does so for me, yes.

Comment: uploaded the resulting image

Comment: Probably. I deleted my comment since I didn't want you to take your answer down, since it's probably the right answer. Still, I think it's better to sort out the intent of the OP first, rather than posting answers to questions that are poorly posed. (For example, I'd like to upvote this, but can't really because the OP may clarify the question in a way that make this answer irrelevant.)

Comment: Yes, I tried made this in double logarithmic scale. Because i was interested if its possible.